# Resizing page doesn't go to scroll bar without absolute width

Tags: html, css, resize, navigationbar

So I have the following page with a navbar: http://michigangurudwara.com/pclass/
and it doesn't look bad, but when you resize the browser, everything overlaps. What I want is for the navbar to fill up the whole width and then when the screen is resized a scroll bar should pop up, but when I do width:100% in the .navbar class, this doesn't happen. The only way to get a scroll bar is with an absolute width. But if I do that, I can't take up the entire screen width for different monitor sizes. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a minimum width...

```
.navbar {
    min-width: 1000px; }
```

Anything less than that will cause the scroll bar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a different style to navigation, to have the nav bar always the same width could make large issues for many users. A better approach is to set the page width to say 1000px; and then have auto sizing margins on either side.

```
.navbar{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

However if your determined to do it this way then you could always get the browser width with Javascript and then use that to set a dynamic width variable.

I was also going to suggest `minimum-width:100%;` but I think you'd still come across the same issue.

The problem is when using percent the template will re-size to the browser width where as pixels will always represent an absolute value as you mention.